# Finding longest common subsequence in O(NlogN) time

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, lcs

Is there any way of finding the longest common subsequence of two sequences in O(NlogN) time?

I read somewhere that there is a way to achieve this using binary search.

I know the dp approach that takes O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

Answer (score 13):

For the general case, the O(N^2) dynamic programming algorithm is the best you can do. However, there exist better algorithms in some special cases.

1. **Alphabet size is bounded**

This is a very common situation. Sequences consisting of letters from some alphabet (e.g. English) lie in this category. For this case, the O(N*M) algorithm can be optimised to get an O(N^2/logN) with [method of four Russians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians). I don't know how exactly, you can search for it.

2. **Both sequences consist of distinct elements**

An example problem is "Given two permutations of numbers from 1 to N, find their LCS". This one can be solved in O(N*logN). 
 Let the sequences be A and B. 
Define a sequence C. C[i] is the index of B[i] in A. (A[C[i]] = B[i])

 LCS of A and B is the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) of C.

Comment: The second case requires only one string to have distinct elements.

Answer (score 4):

The [dynamic programming approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), which is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* for general case. For *certain* other cases, there are lower-complexity algorithms:

- For a fixed alphabet size (which doesn't grow with *n*), there's the [Method of Four Russians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians) which brings the time down to *O(n<sup>2</sup>/log n)* (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Further_optimized_algorithms)).
- See [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/pubs/p-sparsedp.html) another further optimized case.

Comment: There's also the very practical [O(nd) approach of Meyers](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf), where d is the Levenshtein distance between the two strings -- this is O(n) if there are a bounded number of differences.  TTBOMK it's still what's used in `diff`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming [Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) (which is stricter than P is not equal to NP, but is still widely believed to be true), it is not possible to do it in time O(N^{2 - eps}) for any positive constant eps, see ["Quadratic Conditional Lower Bounds for String Problems and Dynamic Time Warping"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2880032) by Karl Bringmann and Marvin Kunnemann (pre-print on arXiv is available).

Roughly speaking, it means that the general case of this problem cannot be solved in time better than something like O(N^2/log N), so if you want faster algorithms you have to consider additional constraints (some properties of the strings) or look for approximate solution.

Answer (score 1):

The longest common subsequence between two sequences is essentially n-squared.

[Masek and Patterson (1980)](http://www.cs.ust.hk/mjg_lib/bibs/DPSu/DPSu.Files/MaPa80.pdf) made a minor improvement to n-squared / log n using the so-called "[Four Russians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians)" technique.

In most cases the additional complexity introduced by such convoluted approaches is not justified by the small gains. For practical purposes you can consider the n-squared approach as the reasonable optimum in typical applications.

Comment: There's also the very practical [O(nd) approach of Meyers](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf), where d is the Levenshtein distance between the two strings -- this is O(n) if there are a bounded number of differences.  TTBOMK it's still what's used in `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <int> LIS;
int LongestIncreasingSubsequence(int n){
    if(!n) return 0;
    LIS.emplace_back(arr[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > LIS.back()) LIS.emplace_back(arr[i]);
        else *lower_bound(LIS.begin(), LIS.end(), arr[i]) = arr[i];
    }
    return LIS.size();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following is a O(NLOGM) approach of the LCS problem that uses binary search:

```
//If the strings are not the same length, take the longest one
//Map each letter with a ArrayList representing the occurences on that letter (indexes)
//The ArrayLists are thus sorted. This will enable binary search later on
Map<Character, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
    char c = first.charAt(i);
    if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
        map.put(c, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(c).add(i);
}

//Loop on the second string and increment an index to check that any matching character is a valid match
//For sequence match we need to maintain the same order as in the initial string so we use an increasing index for that

int index = 0;
StringBuilder lcs = new StringBuilder();

for (int j = 0; j < second.length(); j++) {
    char c = second.charAt(j);
    if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        List<Integer> indexes = map.get(c);
        //The following method uses Binary Search to find the first bigger or equal index
        //This is possible since the indexes list is sorted by definition
        int firstBigger = firstBiggerOrEqualIndex(indexes, index);
        if (firstBigger != -1) {
            index = firstBigger+1;
            lcs.append(c);
        }
    }
}
return lcs.toString();
```

The method firstBiggerOrEqualIndex uses Binary Search like this:

```
private static int firstBiggerOrEqualIndex(List<Integer> indexes, int index) {

    int start = 0;
    int end = indexes.size()-1;
    int res = -1;
    while(start <= end) {
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        int value = indexes.get(mid);
        if (value > index) {
            res = value;
            end = mid-1;
        }
        else if (value == index) {
            res = value;
            break;
        }
        else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```